# iOS: How to ensure tasks are performed in the order that they are queued with NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, ios

Using the NSOperationQueue, how would one ensure that the tasks are executing in the same ordered as it was queued?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-[NSOperationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:]`

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = ...; // Your queue here
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a resource that may answer your question:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Sep/msg01160.html

Written by an apple guy.

"If all operations have the same priority (which is not changed after the operation is added to a queue) and all operations are always - isReady==YES by the time they get put in the operation queue, then a serial NSOperationQueue is FIFO. The second condition I mention there is stronger than "no operation dependencies" -- dependencies don't directly matter to a queue, just the readiness of the operations, and dependencies are just one thing that can affect readiness."

Note: FIFO is First In, First Out.